# One Definition Rule and static member initialization

Tags: c++, static, static-members, one-definition-rule

I've read the one definition rule yet could not find the answer to what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm  implementing a class in which I need to count every occurrence created of this class, let's name it "Item"

Such that when the header and CPP files are complicated, the static member is defined and with every call to the class' constructor, said static member grows by one and applied to current object that is created. (That is how I presume things are happening 'back stage')

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I removed my first comment when you posted your answer.  But the comment I posted below is highly relevant to your future success on SO, so please take the [tour], read [ask] and learn what constitutes a [mre].  Thx.

Comment: Please check the answer and vote and accept accordingly if I understood well your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `Item::idCounter` all along, while I needed to use `int Item::idCounter;`

Weirdly, no flags were raised about this.

Comment: Tough for us to have any idea what might be wrong, with no code to eyeball!

Comment: Indeed, I will supply elaborate details on future questions.

Comment: _I was using Item::idCounter all along_ You mean that's how you defined (as opposed to declared) `Item::idCounter`?  With no type specifier?  What compiler are you using? [gcc rejects that](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JPn61sePFdO8mOqv).

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm using Repl.
Online IDE's are much more convenient, being able to log in and continue my work from anywhere.

Comment: OK, perhaps you could post your original code there and then provide a link to it from here, because I'm as surprised as you.

Comment: @PaulSanders It's a long & boring inheritance exercise, terribly explained & taught.
Luckily, SO allows me to  find answers to upcoming issues and also learn from the answers as I write the code, in contrary to the teaching process in my uni. tuition down the drain.
It's a shame some academic institutions still treat students like we're in the 1960s.

Comment: OK, no probs.  _It's a shame some academic institutions still treat students like we're in the 1960s._ Amen to that, we see loads of that here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is essentially a Singleton model.
here are 3 files working example:
test.h

```
class myClass{
    protected:
        static myClass *hinst;
        int inst_count;
        myClass();
        ~myClass();
    public:
        static myClass * getInstance();
        int count() const;
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

myClass::myClass(){
    this->inst_count=0;
}

myClass *myClass::hinst = 0;

myClass * myClass::getInstance(){
    if(hinst==0)
        hinst = new myClass();
            
    myClass::hinst->inst_count++;
    return myClass::hinst;  
}

int myClass::count() const{
    return this->inst_count;            
}
```

test_main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){
    myClass *pp= myClass::getInstance();

    printf("%ld\n", pp->count());
    printf("%ld\n", myClass::getInstance());
    printf("%ld\n", myClass::getInstance());
    printf("%ld\n", myClass::getInstance());
    printf("%ld\n", myClass::getInstance());
    printf("%ld\n", pp->count());
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, Run and output

```
> c++  test_main.cpp test.cpp -o test_main.exe && test_main
1
3878864
3878864
3878864
3878864
5
```

Comment: Why must I use it as a pointer? I've used it as a value.

Comment: It’s not a pointer, it’s a value